React sticky header flickers on scroll - IntersectionObserver and CSS issues
I'm implementing a sticky header in a React application(carbon is the framework in use). The header is supposed to be sticky and have a border bottom when a user scrolls up so that they have context of what they are viewing, and when they scroll down to the original page display, the header should not be sticky and should not have a border bottom. I am using the Intersection Observer API, but I'm experiencing a flickering issue when scrolling. I am using IntersectionObserver to detect when the header should become sticky by applying CSS classes based on the sticky state using a debounced state update to prevent rapid changes.
Any recommendations or advise on how i can achieve the expected behaviour will be appreciated. Here (drive.google.com) is the video with the behaviour.
Reproduction (codesnadbox.io)
const [showStickyHeader, setShowStickyHeader] = useState(false);
const observer = useRef(null);
const debouncedSetShowStickyHeader = useRef(
  debounce((value) => setShowStickyHeader(value), 50)
).current;

const stickyMenuHeaderRef = useCallback(
  (node) => {
    if (observer.current) {
      observer.current.disconnect();
    }

    if (node) {
      observer.current = new IntersectionObserver(
        ([entry]) => {
          const shouldStick = entry.intersectionRatio < 0.95;
          debouncedSetShowStickyHeader(shouldStick);
        },
        {
          threshold: [0, 0.95, 1],
          rootMargin: '0px 0px -5px 0px',
        }
      );
      observer.current.observe(node);
    }

    return () => {
      if (observer.current) {
        observer.current.disconnect();
      }
      debouncedSetShowStickyHeader.cancel();
    };
  },
  [debouncedSetShowStickyHeader]
);

.resultsHeader {
  padding: var(--spacing-03) 0;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: var(--openmrs-background-grey);
  top: var(--spacing-09);
  display: flex;
}

.stickyResultsHeader {
  padding: var(--spacing-03) 0;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: var(--openmrs-background-grey);
  top: var(--spacing-09);
  display: flex;
  position: sticky;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1e1;
}


We would need a minimal reproduction.

@rozsazoltan https://codesandbox.io/p/live/64aeba5f-2c20-4b6a-ba12-6e8103584961

Thanks! With the running code, I was able to see how it works and the error much faster than by pasting it here. Although I agree that the logical error was already present in the pasted code, I found it hard to notice without reproduction.

Solution (with your code)
// set true, set false, set true... loop
const shouldStick = entry.intersectionRatio < 0.95; 

In your code, you depend on the value of entry.intersectionRatio to determine whether the sticky state should be true or false. This condition should not be less than 0.95 but should be exactly equal to 1.
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
  ([entry]) => {
    if (entry.intersectionRatio < 0.95) {
      console.log('Element is less than 95% visible');
    } else {
      console.log('Element is at least 95% visible');
    }
  },
);

// entry.intersectionRatio maybe will 0.5 --> set sticky state to true
// now by sticky style, entry.intersectionRatio will be 1.0 --> 1.0 < 0.95 === false --> set sticky state to false
// ... loop

When you set the sticky state, the value of entry.intersectionRatio will be 1, which is greater than 0.95, and that's why you get an infinite loop.
// set true (end)
const shouldStick = entry.intersectionRatio === 1;

// or: Although I don't see much point in this
const shouldStick = entry.intersectionRatio > 0.95;

Alternative solution (just use CSS position: sticky;)
Although you are currently using it, the sticky position works as you expect even without your JS code. When the element reaches the specified distance from the top in pixels, it becomes fixed there as you continue scrolling. Since you set top: 0, the element will stay fixed when it reaches the 0 pixel position of its parent element.
const stickyResultsHeader = {
  // design
  padding: "1.5rem 0",
  backgroundColor: "gray",
  display: "flex",
  borderBottom: "1px solid #e1e1e1e1",
  // for sticky state
  position: shouldSticky ? "sticky" : "block", // only drawback in the function is that the switch does not toggle back automatically to sticky
  top: "0",
  zIndex: 10,
};

<div style={stickyResultsHeader}>
  <div style={leftSectionStyle}>
    <h4>Tests</h4>
    <Button kind="ghost" size="md">
      <span>Reset</span> <!-- onClick set shouldSticky to false -->
    </Button>
  </div>
</div>

